# Javascript make button unclickable

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is that, I have button like below

```
<button type="button" id="btn_all">All</button>
<button type="button" id="btn_A">A</button>
<button type="button" id="btn_B">B</button>
<button type="button" id="btn_C">C</button>
```

And my javascript is

```
let btn_all = document.getElementById("btn_all");
let btn_A = document.getElementById("btn_A");
let btn_B = document.getElementById("btn_B");
let btn_C = document.getElementById("btn_C");

let allButtons = [btn_all,btn_A,btn_B,btn_C];

let abt = btn_A.style.backgroundColor = "red";

function changeColor (e) {
    
    let currentColor = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
    if (currentColor != "red") {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }else{       
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
    
}

function changeColorAll (e) {
    let currentColor = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
    if (currentColor != "red") {
        allButtons.forEach( function(element, index) {
            
            element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            
        });
    }
    else {
        allButtons.forEach( function(element, index) {
            if (index === (allButtons.length -3)) {
                
                element.style.backgroundColor = "red";

            }else{
                element.style.backgroundColor = "";
            }
            
        });
    }
}

btn_all.addEventListener("click", changeColorAll);
btn_A.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
btn_B.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
btn_C.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
```

1 - When I click on button A,B,C, to change it's background to red, button All also change it's **backgroudColor** to red.

2- When I click on All button to change its and others to no **backgroudColor**, at least one button still red and prevent it not changeable the color.
Anybody can help please.

UPDATE

I want to update my problems.

1 - When I first load the page all four button has no backgroudcolor except button A has background in red. If I click on B, C, button, I want button All change to red also.

2- When I click on button All to change all button to no background color, I want one of these buttons( A, B, C) still red and can not click to change color.

Comment: Could you provide your codes on an online editor like Jsfiddle/codepen so that we can check the output?

Comment: Here is my code in https://jsfiddle.net/47g6fmzd/

Comment: Could you clarify what the expected behaviour for each button click is?

Comment: I want to update my problems. It's may because my English is not good enough to explain to you of my problem. 1 - When I first load the page all four button has no backgroudcolor except button A has background in red. If I click on B, C, button, I want button All change to red also. 2- When I click on button All to change all button to no background color, I want one of these buttons( A, B, C) still red and can not click to change color. If you have anything for me to clarify please tell me. I really need this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your 1st point, add a condition in the `changeColor` method to check whether all the buttons are red or not.

```
if (btn_A.style.backgroundColor == "red" && btn_B.style.backgroundColor == "red" && btn_C.style.backgroundColor == "red") {
    btn_all.style.backgroundColor = "red";
} else {
    btn_all.style.backgroundColor = "";
}
```

For your 2nd point, remove the if-else condition from the `changeColorAll` else part and just update the color directly.

```
function changeColorAll (e) {
let currentColor = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
if (currentColor != "red") {
    allButtons.forEach( function(element, index) {
        
        element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        
    });
}
else {
    allButtons.forEach( function(element, index) {
            element.style.backgroundColor = "";
            btn_A.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    });
}}
```

Also, add a condition in the `changeColor` to check whether all the buttons are not of red color, if not then change the color of a button

```
if (btn_A.style.backgroundColor == "" && btn_B.style.backgroundColor == "" && btn_C.style.backgroundColor == "") {
    btn_A.style.backgroundColor = "red"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//HTML
$('#Button').prop('disabled', true);
//JS
document.getElementById("Button").disabled = !0;
```